# Java-Trouble outputting an ArrayList in readable format

Tags: java, arraylist

To keep it brief, i'm trying to output a list, however whenever I do i'm only seeing the CLASS@IFI342 type format. I can't use the toString method as the list contains objects, not integers etc. Does anyone know how to get around this? The list contains a number of bed types, so either single or double. I've tried using a .equals but this had no effect. Thanks

```
System.out.println("Room 1 has " + r1.getNumberOfBeds() + " beds:");
    for (int i = 0; i < r1.getNumberOfBeds(); i++){
        if (h.beds.get(i).equals("Single")){
            System.out.println("Single");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Double");
        }
    }
```

Comment: in your bed class you can override the to string method and then the to string method should work fine

Comment: Sorry how do you do this?

Comment: if you are using eclipse you can go into your bed class, right click->source->generate tostring

Comment: Perfect. Thank you